# How to Implement Custom Method Options as with Regex.Match

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a method which accepts options like the way Regex.Match accepts RegexOptions.

So for example I have a method like:

```
        private static void UpdateState(Record record, string state)
        {
            record.State = state;
        }
```

But instead of the parameter "string state" I want this to be a parameter like "System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions options" in the below example:

```
public static System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match Match (string input, string pattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions options, TimeSpan matchTimeout);
```

I can simply accept the string parameter and pass in static read only members of a class but this doesn't achieve the desired outcome because I could pass in just any string.

So I would like to be able to pass parameters in like this:

```
UpdateState(record, Record.Closed);
```

How can I do this properly and restrict the values which can be passed in to my own set of custom predefined options?

Comment: Instead of options you could use action, comparable to Ef-fluent api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [`RegexOptions` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=netframework-4.8), you'll see that it's an `enum`.

If you research that, you'll find that you can [declare your own enumeration type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum):

```
public enum MyMethodOptions
{
    Option1 = 1,
    Option2 = 2,
    Option3 = 4,
    // ...

}
```

Now you can declare a method that accepts a parameter of that type:

```
public void MyFoo(MyMethodOptions options) { ... }
```

And call it:

```
MyFoo(MyMethodOptions.Option1 | MyMethodOptions.Option3);
```

Comment: Worth mentioning, it does not have to be an enum, it can also be any object/class.

Comment: @Fabo what do you mean?

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction and providing a sample solution.

Comment: @CodeCaster: thatthe Options object does not have to be an enum, but it can be for example a static or dynamic class. 

This can be useful, if you want to have a bit more complex options where you want to set specific facets of it.
Or if you want to have different implementations of a method based on what the option is.

For an examle of what I mean in standard .NET, you can look at System.Text.Encoding for example.